# Access & send iMessage through watchkit extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, ios8-extension

I want to access iMessage and send message to another user via that but using iMessage ?
I have googled it but could not find any thing ?
Is it possible and if yes how can I do that ?

-Thanks in advance.

Aakil

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access iMessage, our only option is to the the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html) to allow to user to send a message. If iMessage is available for the receiving party the message will be send by iMessage. Otherwise it will be send as an SMS or MMS.

Since `MFMessageComposeViewController` is only available in UIKit and not in WatchKit you will not be able to send message via a watch kit extension.

Comment: thanks man. That means I can not even access MFMessageComposeViewController in Watchkit Extension ?

Comment: If I could make a suggestion: Consider prompting the user to use Handoff to open your app and present custom sharing UI.